# Personalized Attachment

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Is it possible to create and send personalized PDF (e:g order details) and send as attachment in Marketing Cloud email?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily see this question already has a correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, however there are different methods to do so. You could either upload the file to the enhanced FTP and pass the pdf-name (order number for example) to the send. Another option would be attaching the file from a server you own.

**Overview of enhanced FTP solution:**

- As soon as the order is placed, your system that handles the orders needs to trigger the upload of your personalized PDF to the Marketing Cloud Enhanced FTP
- Trigger the send of the email and add the name of the pdf to the attributes passed to the send (either to the triggered send or the journey entry)
- Write the passed value to an AMPscript variable
- Use that variable to build the path to the file (using Contact-function for example)
- Attach the file using the generated path and the AttachFile-function

**Example code that needs to be adapted to your needs:**

```java
%%[
    Var @filename
    Set @filename = AttributeValue('filename')
]%%

%%=AttachFile('FTP', Concat('folderNameForOrderPdfs/', @filename), 'FileNameOfAttachmentInEmail.pdf')=%%
```

**Related documentation:**

- [Enhanced FTP Guide](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/enhanced_ftp_guide/)
- [AttachFile function reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm)
- [Concat function reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Concat.htm)

Comment: Just to note that the "AttachFile()" function is actually quite pricey to activate and use from what I recall.

Comment: As far as I know (at least in the product package my company has) there is no additional charge for actually using this function. However maybe the price of provisioning afterwards if it isn't already available in the account differs.